# Various Interpretations of Condition Number

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

Condition number of a matrix $A$ signifies how quickly solution $x$ changes in $Ax = b$ as we make small changes in $b$. This is given by $||A||.||A^{-1}||$. When we consider spectral norm, this turns out to be the ratio of largest singular value of $A$ to the smallest singular value of $A$. This ratio of singular values can be interpreted as how deformed an ellipsoid we get when we apply $A$ to the sphere. I don't exactly understand how this interpretation of condition number is connected to the earlier interpretation where we are concerned about the change in solution $x$. I understand the connection algebraically and I am looking for a more intuitive explanation.

Comment: I, too, have the same question, have you been able to find a satisfying answer in the past 4 years?

Comment: I have the same question. My quest is simpler, that take a 2x2 matrix and a 2D plane for a concrete setting: solving $Ax=b$ is equal to finding intersection of two lines in the 2D plane. Intuitively, it's easy to show that if the two lines are close to parallel, the position of the intersection is highly sensitive to $b$. The slope of the two lines can be represented by two points (vectors) in the plane, each has a coordinate specified by a row of $A$. The two lines are perpendicular to the two vectors respectively. Continue this line of intuition, how to interpret condition number of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've convinced yourself that the condition number is given by $\|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\|$ (using a derivation such as that presented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices)), it suffices to note that
$$
\|A\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| = \sigma_1(A)\\
\|A^{-1}\| = \left[\min_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\|\right]^{-1} = \frac 1{\sigma_n(A)}
$$
Note that $\{x : \|x\| = 1\}$ is the unit sphere, and $\{Ax: \|x\| = 1\}$ is the ellipsoid we get by applying $A$.  By our above definition, $\|A\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$ gives us the greatest distance of a point on the ellipsoid from the origin, i.e. the length of the "major radius" of the ellipsoid.  $\min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$ gives us the least distance of a point on the ellipsoid from the origin, i.e. the length of the "minor radius" of the ellipsoid.  The ratio of these two length is a measure of how deformed the ellipsoid is.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But as I mentioned in the details of my question, I understand things algebraically as presented by you. I am looking for a more intuitive explanation of why the two interpretations are equivalent.

Comment: @user2684957 well, it wasn't clear what "understanding things algebraically" entails.  Is there a step taken in my explanation which is unintuitive, then?

Comment: @user2684957 For example, perhaps the unintuitive step is from the definition "how quickly solution $x$ changes in $Ax=b$ as we make small changes in $b$" to the matrix-norm formula $\|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\|$

Comment: I don't think that the explanation
$$
\kappa(A) = \frac{\max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|}{\min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|}
$$
is usually given, and I think it makes things pretty intuitive.

Comment: I understand that $||A||.||A^{-1}||$  is ratio of major radius to minor radius. $||A||.||A^{-1}||$ also represents how fast $x$ changes in the system $Ax = b$ as we make small changes in $b$. I am able to understand algebraically why these quantities are same, i.e. I am able to follow each step of the proof of their equivalence. But I am not able to form a big picture of why they should be equal. Just given these 2 interpretation, how would one see geometrically that they are equivalent. I am looking for a plain english geometric explanation.

Comment: Can you understand that both of these should be equal to the ratio $\frac{\max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|}{\min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|}$?

Comment: I understand intuitively that the deformation of a sphere  corresponds to this ratio. But I don't understand intuitively why change in solution $x$ corresponds to this.

Comment: @user2684957 That's something I can work with.  I'll add something.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to improve the wikipedia explanation.  The condition number is a worst-case upper bound for the ratio
$$
\left(\frac{\|\Delta x\|}{\|x\|}\right)\Big / \left(\frac{\|\Delta b\|}{\|b\|}\right)
$$
which is the same as a worst case upper bound to
$$
\frac{\|\Delta x\|}{\|\Delta b\|} \cdot \frac{\|b\|}{\|x\|}
$$